# Run Presto on JDK 6

Tags: presto, java-6, trino

I tried to run the launcher but encountered this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: sun/misc/FloatingDecimal : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
    at java.lang.Double.toString(Double.java:196)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2985)
    at java.security.Provider.putId(Provider.java:433)
    at java.security.Provider.<init>(Provider.java:137)
    at sun.security.jca.ProviderList$1.<init>(ProviderList.java:71)
    at sun.security.jca.ProviderList.<clinit>(ProviderList.java:70)
    at sun.security.jca.Providers.<clinit>(Providers.java:56)
    at sun.security.util.ManifestEntryVerifier.<clinit>(ManifestEntryVerifier.java:47)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.initializeVerifier(JarFile.java:335)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.getInputStream(JarFile.java:410)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader$2.getInputStream(URLClassPath.java:721)
    at sun.misc.Resource.cachedInputStream(Resource.java:77)
    at sun.misc.Resource.getByteBuffer(Resource.java:160)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:266)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:212)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
Could not find the main class: com.facebook.presto.server.PrestoServer. Program will exit.
```

I think that it is because I run the launcher on JDK 6.(whereas it required JDK 7.) Is there any version of Presto that can run on JDK 6? Because I currently want to run it on my Cloudera Hadoop cluster and Cloudera seems only to work well with JDK 6.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Presto is only compatible with Java 7.

You should be able to install both Java 6 and 7 on the same machine. You just need to make sure Java 7's bin directory is in your PATH before you start the presto launcher.

Answer (score 3):

Presto will definitely not work with JDK 6. In addition to heavily using features like try-with-resources, the bytecode compiler for queries is all based on `invokedynamic`. JDK 7 is substantially faster, not to mention that JDK 6 has been end of life since February.

That said, you can easily have both JDKs installed on the same machine and use JDK 6 for Hadoop and JDK 7 for Presto. The Presto launcher will simply use whichever `java` is first in `PATH`, so put JDK 7 first in your `PATH` before running the launcher.